# Perl library Error message every time after logging to a server

Tags: perl

I will try to make my problem as clear as possible.

After logging to a server I get this message:

```
 Last login: Sat Apr 13 02:52:11 2013 from this_and_that
 Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /.../perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /.../perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your shell startup files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`). It seems that you have a command for [bootstrapping local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008009/lib/local/lib.pm#The_bootstrapping_technique) there which throws the error.